# Package Dependencies cannot be resolved!! Please Help!

Tags: 12.04, software-center, wine

When I try to download something, in this case it was Wine, from the Ubuntu Software Center, I get this...

```
wine1.4: PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.15.7.2~) but 1.16.1.2ubuntu7.1 will be installed
         Depends: libc6 (>= 2.14) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.3 will be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-amd64 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4) but 1.4-0ubuntu4 will be installed
         Depends: wine1.4-i386 (= 1.4-0ubuntu4) but is a virtual package
```

I'm a recent Ubuntu user so, i don't get any of this x:

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Wine this way, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5 && sudo apt-get install winetricks
```